# ComboBox ItemsSource error within Grid Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, devexpress

I want implement comboBox in a Grid Control. After searching in tne net I found 2 solutions and every solution have problem :

1. Using **ComboBoxEditSettings** as shown below but I couldn't implement property EditValue=".." because ComboBoxEditSettings don't support it.

   ```
        <dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilterList,Mode=TwoWay}" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">
           <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
               <dxg:GridColumn Header="Table" FieldName="Table" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" AllowEditing="True" >
             <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings  >

              <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings  IsTextEditable="False" ItemsSource="{ Binding FilterTables}"   >
                </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
             </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
   ```
2. Using **ComboBoxEdit** within **DataTemplate** but nothing shows up in my comboBox.

   ```
   <dxg:GridColumn Header="Table" FieldName="Table" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" AllowEditing="True" >   
   <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <dxe:ComboBoxEdit AutoComplete="True" IsTextEditable="False"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding FilterTables, Mode=TwoWay}">
           </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
         </DataTemplate>
   ```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _filterTables;
public ObservableCollection<string> FilterTables
        {
            get { return _filterTables; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _filterTables, value, () => FilterTables); 
            }
        }
```

So My question is how can I use comboBox and the property EditValue=".." Within GridControl ?

Comment: I'm trying too to find solution. I'm not able to compare devExpress Vs Standard Wpf because from my first step I started work Wpf within DevExpress.

Comment: Standard WPF is a lot easier. DevExpress don't follow a common way of doing things.